# Rendering OpenGL mesh to SFML RenderTexture

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am trying to use a combination of SFML and OpenGL for a project, but I am having trouble rendering to a `sf::RenderTexture`.  Specifically, if I try to draw while the `RenderTexture` is active, I crash.  (Looks like a null pointer dereference inside `glDrawElements`.)

Rendering directly to the window works fine.  And if I manually create a framebuffer through OpenGL myself, that also works fine.  But I'd like to be able to use `RenderTexture` if possible to simplify a lot of the code.

I may be doing something stupid, but I'm still new to OpenGL so I'm not sure.  (Especially with the mixture of SFML and OpenGL, it seems like a lot of stuff can break if you don't manage the context switching correctly.)  I'm not seeing any warnings from OpenGL or SFML.

The following reproduces the issue I'm seeing (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, OpenGL 4.5, GLEW 2.1.0, SFML 2.4.0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

GLenum glCheckError_(const char *file, int line)
{
    GLenum errorCode;
    while ((errorCode = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::string error;
        switch (errorCode)
        {
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:                  error = "INVALID_ENUM"; break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:                 error = "INVALID_VALUE"; break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:             error = "INVALID_OPERATION"; break;
        case GL_STACK_OVERFLOW:                error = "STACK_OVERFLOW"; break;
        case GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW:               error = "STACK_UNDERFLOW"; break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:                 error = "OUT_OF_MEMORY"; break;
        case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: error = "INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION"; break;
        }
        std::cerr << error << " | " << file << " (" << line << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return errorCode;
}
#define glCheckError() glCheckError_(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "test");
    glewInit();
    std::cout << "Using OpenGL " << window.getSettings().majorVersion << "." << window.getSettings().minorVersion << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Available GL extensions: " << glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) << std::endl;

    sf::Shader shader;
    { // Shader
        const char* vs = R"(
            #version 330 core
            layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
            }
        )";
        const char* fs = R"(
            #version 330 core
            out vec4 color;

            void main()
            {
                color = vec4(0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0);
            }
        )";
        shader.loadFromMemory(vs, fs);
    }

    unsigned int vao;
    { // Mesh
        float vertices[] = {
             0.3f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  // top right
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  // bottom right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  // bottom left
            -0.3f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  // top left
        };
        unsigned int indices[] = {
            0, 3, 1,  // first triangle
            1, 3, 2,  // second triangle
        };
        unsigned int vbo, ebo;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glCheckError();
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glCheckError();
        glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
        glCheckError();
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glCheckError();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glCheckError();

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glCheckError();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
        glCheckError();
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glCheckError();

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glCheckError();

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glCheckError();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glCheckError();
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glCheckError();
    }

    sf::RenderTexture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    { // Render Texture
        if (!texture.create(800, 600, true)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create RenderTexture" << std::endl;
        }
        sprite.setTexture(texture.getTexture());
    }

    int frame = 0;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        ++frame;
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        if (frame > 1)
        {
            window.popGLStates();
        }

        { // Render to screen
            sf::Shader::bind(&shader);
            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            glCheckError();

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            glCheckError();

            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glCheckError();
            sf::Shader::bind(nullptr);
        }

        window.pushGLStates();
        window.display();

        // Press space to continue...
        bool waiting = true;
        while (waiting) {
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
                {
                    waiting = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        if (frame > 1)
        {
            window.popGLStates();
        }

        { // Render to texture
            sf::Shader::bind(&shader);
            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            glCheckError();

            texture.pushGLStates();
            if (!texture.setActive(true)) { // TODO Setting the texture as active is causing me to segfault, messing up my state somehow
                std::cerr << "Failed to activate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
            }
            texture.clear();
            texture.popGLStates();

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // <-- Crashes here!
            glCheckError();

            texture.pushGLStates();
            texture.display();
            if (!texture.setActive(false)) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to deactivate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
            }
            texture.popGLStates();

            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glCheckError();
            sf::Shader::bind(nullptr);
        }

        window.pushGLStates();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
};
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Well I've solved the crashing part.  `sf::RenderTexture`s have their own GL context, and I guess you can't reuse data between contexts.  So I had to generate the texture first and use `texture.setActive()` before generating the shader and mesh.  That way the context has those objects available.

Now I am just getting a black screen.  I am able to draw a new `sf::RectangleShape` to the same `RenderTexture`, but my GL mesh doesn't seem to be drawing.  Still investigating...

In case anyone has the same issue, here are snippets of what I had to change:

```
// --- initialization ---

// Generate the texture first so its context is available
sf::RenderTexture texture;
sf::Sprite sprite;
{ // Render Texture
    if (!texture.create(800, 600, true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
    sprite.setTexture(texture.getTexture());
}

// Generate the rest of the data within the texture's context
sf::Shader shader;
{ // Shader
    if (!texture.setActive(true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
    shader.loadFromMemory(vs, fs);
    if (!texture.setActive(false)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to deactivate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
}

unsigned int vao;
{ // Mesh
    if (!texture.setActive(true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
    unsigned int vbo, ebo;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glCheckError();
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glCheckError();

    // ...

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glCheckError();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glCheckError();
    if (!texture.setActive(false)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to deactivate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
}

// --- drawing ---

{ // Render to texture
    // Make sure we use the appropriate context for all drawing to texture
    if (!texture.setActive(true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
    texture.clear();
    sf::Shader::bind(&shader);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glCheckError();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // TODO rendering nothing here...
    glCheckError();

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glCheckError();
    sf::Shader::bind(nullptr);

    // Drawing to the texture through SFML works fine
    texture.pushGLStates();
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
    texture.draw(rect);
    texture.popGLStates();

    texture.display();
    if (!texture.setActive(false)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to deactivate RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
}

if (!window.setActive(true)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to activate window" << std::endl;
}
window.pushGLStates();
window.draw(sprite);
window.display();
```

**EDIT 2:** Drawing problems solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!  All thanks to "Groogy" in this thread: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=7446.0

I had skimmed that thread earlier, which prompted me to add `texture.setView(texture.getDefaultView());` when creating the `RenderTexture`.  However that was not enough, I instead had to call `glViewport` with the texture bound.  (I assumed that is what `sf::View` would do under the covers, but apparently that is not the case.)

So my `RenderTexture` creation now looks like this:

```
sf::RenderTexture texture;
sf::Sprite sprite;
{ // Render Texture
    if (!texture.create(800, 600, true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create RenderTexture" << std::endl;
    }
    if (!texture.setActive(true)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate texture" << std::endl;
    }
    sprite.setTexture(texture.getTexture());

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); // <-- Required
    glCheckError();

    if (!texture.setActive(false)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to deactivate texture" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And now things are working.